# How to commit related models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working with ember-pre4 and ember-data rev 11.

Models:

```
A = DS.Model.extend({
    //some other fields
    b: DS.hasMany('B')
})
B = DS.Model.extend({
    //some other fields
    a: DS.hasOne('A') 
})
```

In my router I create an instance of model A and create an instance of model B and connect them. They both don't have server-side `id`. Something like this:

```
var a = A.createRecord();
    b = B.createRecord();
b.set('a', a)
a.get('b').addObject(b)
```

When I want to save those models I make:

```
a.transaction.commit()
```

And I expected to see:

1. Save a with empty b // []
2. After saving a pass a's id into b and save b
3. After saving b refetch a

But unfortunately ember does 2 request in parallel and a's request data is:

```
"{//some fields, b: [/url_to_b//]}" // we dont have b's id
```

b's request data is:

```
"{//some fields } // we dont have a's id
```

What is the best way to solve this problem, does new ember have a default solution for my situation or I should do all stuff manually?

Comment: Did you come up with any solutions? I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
I wrapped createRecord function in waitForParents function:

```
waitForParents:function (record, callback, context) {
    var observers = new Em.Set();

    record.eachRelationship(function (name, meta) {
        var relationship = get(record, name);

        if (meta.kind === 'belongsTo' && relationship && get(relationship, 'isNew')) {
            var observer = function () {
                relationship.removeObserver('id', context, observer);
                observers.remove(name);
                finish();
            };

            relationship.addObserver('id', context, observer);
            observers.add(name);
        }
    });

    finish();

    function finish() {
        if (observers.length === 0) {
            callback.call(context);
        }
    }
},

createRecord:function (store, type, record) {
   this.waitForParents(record, function () {   
   // createRecord code here 
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. What do you do inside the waitForParent callback? Do you just call this._super() for createrecord? The problem with me is that only one request is fired (which is correct) but in the request data the child's url is automatically embedded but it's incomplete (id is missing e.g. /api/v1/child//).

Comment: To solve this problem i override addBelongsTo function from serializer.       
    addBelongsTo:function (hash, record, key, relationship) {
        var id = get(record, relationship.key + '.id');

        if (!Em.isNone(id)) {
            hash[key] = this.getItemUrl(relationship, id);
        }
    },

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem. The reason is because in my case it's the hasMany relationship that causes the problem. So if anything i should override the addHasMany method in the serializer. How do you add the relationship before commiting? Do you add an object to the hasmany relationship or do you set the belongsTo relationship for the child model?

Comment: addHasMany function (serializing function for hasMany relation) adds related record to parent only if you specified embedded:'always', it can either include id (if it exists) or not (you can check it store.serialize function). A lot of stuff depends on your backend, i mean that some REST APIs support related objects on create request, i.e {static_field: value, related_field: {static_field: value}} can create 2 objects and relate them on the backend. In my example i dont support embedded: 'always' and use 'load'.

Comment: I see. In my case I has embedded: 'always'. It worked for me by overriding addHasMany.